# Is this a SVG rendering bug in Chrome (but not Firefox)?

Tags: css, svg, browser-bugs

I have an SVG that must be positioned absolutely and doesn't have a width/height because it's unknown at runtime. However, it does have `overflow: visible` set to allow content to be rendered at any coordinate.

When the SVG has an element like a `<path>` or `<circle>` that is very far along the y-axis (e.g. 4000 pixels), the SVG seems to be rendered offset in Chrome. In Firefox, the SVG renders correctly at the right coordinates.

What's even more strange is that if I set `cursor` on the element, it appears at the correct location, not the rendered location.

Here's an example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const canvasZoom = document.getElementById('canvasZoom');

canvasZoom.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const zoom = canvasZoom.value;
  canvas.style.zoom = zoom;
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 4200px;
  height: 4200px;
}

#line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#line path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  cursor: move;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4000px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="canvasZoom" min="0" max="1" value="100" step="0.05">
<div id="canvas">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="line">
    <path d="M 350 4000 L 350 4100" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="350" cy="4050" r="10" fill="blue" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Firefox (expected):

[image: Firefox]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

If the SVG elements have coordinates near the top, it renders correctly.

I've tried setting things like `width: 100%; height: 100%` but it doesn't fix it. For example, zooming in and out causes the rendering to be incorrect again.

If I set the `width` and `height` of the SVG equal to the parent element, it renders correctly. However, this is not possible or desired in the true implementation.

Comment: You can report Chrome bugs [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: I understand that the SVG needs to be offset but would it be OK if the elements (path and circle) where positioned according to the SVG (like the circle would be cy="50" instead of cy="4050") and then have a viewBox like `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` and then the SVG could be positioned within the #box. And #box would then be moved to top: 4000px. ANd following that: would it be OK to have the SVG inside #box?

Comment: specify a ``viewBox``, an undefined viewBox is different on Chromium (0 values) and FireFox (null value)

Comment: Does it make any difference if you add `html,body {margin:0;padding:0}`?

Comment: @chrwahl without `viewBox`, I can translate the points on the path/circle and offset the SVG to the calculated bounds of the path/circle. It just causes other issues in the real implementation. I'm trying to keep the coordinates of the SVG to match the coordinates of the position container (the canvas). Adjusting margin/padding has no effect.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman what values are you suggesting for `viewBox`? The goal is to not specify a viewBox so that the `path`, `circle` and other children can use the coorindate system of the viewport.

Comment: Renders exactly the same for me on Chrome 93 & 96 & on Firefox 92 on macOS.

Comment: @Kaiido interesting! I'm on Chrome 93/Firefox 92 on Windows 10 with DPI scaling at 125%.

Comment: I can also confirm it renders correctly on Chrome 93 on Android.